# Tensorboard error while training with Yolov7

Tags: python, pytorch, torch, tensorboard, yolov7

I'm trying to use tensorboard according to training instructions of yolov7 to see the results as I'm training.

It said to run this command to view it at http://localhost:6006/

However, I get this error when I run it:

```
(yolov7) C:\Users\user\Documents\Python\yolov7>tensorboard --logdir=runs/train
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\yolov7\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\yolov7\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\yolov7\Scripts\tensorboard.exe\__main__.py", line 4, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\yolov7\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\main.py", line 27, in <module>
    from tensorboard import default
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\yolov7\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\default.py", line 33, in <module>
    from tensorboard.plugins.audio import audio_plugin
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\yolov7\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\plugins\audio\audio_plugin.py", line 23, in <module>
    from tensorboard import plugin_util
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\envs\yolov7\lib\site-packages\tensorboard\plugin_util.py", line 24, in <module>
    import markdown
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\markdown\__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from .core import Markdown, markdown, markdownFromFile  # noqa: E402
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\markdown\core.py", line 26, in <module>
    from . import util
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\markdown\util.py", line 87, in <module>
    INSTALLED_EXTENSIONS = metadata.entry_points().get('markdown.extensions', ())
AttributeError: 'EntryPoints' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Couldn't find any documentation to see what I'm missing.